# My Light Has No Shadow Menu

Tags: light, shadows

When I click on my light there is no shadow menu on the right as the image shows, I am wondering how do I get this menu back? I am currently running blender 2.8 on Linux. Thank you in advance for all your help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using **Cycles** as your rendering engine. Only **EEVEE** has that shadow setting panel:

[image]

Things happen a lot between Cycles and EEVEE, beware of what engine are you using.

Comment: thank you so much.. sorry I am brand new to blender and did know the engine would change the menus